# Oracle - Insert x amount of rows with random data

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am currently doing some testing and am in the need for a large amount of data (around 1 million rows)

I am using the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderTable(
OrderID INTEGER NOT NULL,
StaffID INTEGER,
TotalOrderValue DECIMAL (8,2)
CustomerID INTEGER);

ALTER TABLE OrderTable ADD CONSTRAINT OrderID_PK PRIMARY KEY (OrderID) 

CREATE SEQUENCE seq_OrderTable
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10000;
```

and want to randomly insert 1000000 rows into it with the following rules:

1. OrderID needs to be be sequential (1, 2, 3 etc...)
2. StaffID needs to be a random number between 1 and 1000
3. CustomerID needs to be a random number between 1 and 10000
4. TotalOrderValue needs to be a random decimal value between 0.00 and 9999.99

Is this even possible to do? I can I could generate all of these using this update statement? however generating a million rows in 1 go I am not sure on how to do this

Thanks for any help on this matter

This is how i would randomly generate the number on update:

```
UPDATE StaffTable SET DepartmentID = DBMS_RANDOM.value(low => 1, high => 5);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For testing purposes I created the table and populated it in one shot, with this query:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderTable(OrderID, StaffID, CustomerID, TotalOrderValue)
as (select level, ceil(dbms_random.value(0, 1000)), 
                  ceil(dbms_random.value(0,10000)), 
                  round(dbms_random.value(0,10000),2) 
    from dual 
    connect by level <= 1000000)
/
```

A few notes - it is better to use NUMBER as data type, NUMBER(8,2) is the format for decimal. It is much more efficient for populating this kind of table to use the "hierarchical query without PRIOR" trick (the "connect by level <= ..." trick) to get the order ID's.

If your table is created already, `insert into OrderTable (select level...)` (same subquery as in my code) should work just as well. You may be better off adding the PK constraint only after you create the data though, so as not to slow things down.

A small sample from the table created (total time to create the table on my cheap laptop - 1,000,000 rows - was 7.6 seconds):

```
SQL> select * from OrderTable where orderid between 500020 and 500030;

   ORDERID    STAFFID CUSTOMERID TOTALORDERVALUE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------
    500020        666        879         6068.63
    500021        189       6444         1323.82
    500022        533       2609         1847.21
    500023        409        895          207.88
    500024         80       2125         1314.13
    500025        247       3772         5081.62
    500026        922       9523         1160.38
    500027        818       5197         5009.02
    500028        393       6870         5067.81
    500029        358       4063          858.44
    500030        316       8134         3479.47
```

Comment: Perfect :) thank you, I shall replace this with the method I have just found which was not as easy to understand as this.. And thank you for the tips on the formatting